# Google Maps & Jquery Mobile - map not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps, jquery-mobile

Currently building a basic business directory using Jquery Mobile. I am building it as a web app with plans on using PhoneGap to port it to iOS and Android. The app uses JSON data as its data source.

The app is using individual .html pages for each view. Basic navigation structure is as follows:
Categories -> Businesses -> Business Info

On the Business Info page (so 3 pages deep), I want to display all of the specific business info, as well as Google Map integration with a pin for that business. I first built the app without Jquery Mobile and everything worked perfectly, all info displayed along with correct map. After implementing Jquery Mobile, problems occurred.

Initially my code was wrapped in function initialize(){}, which ended just after my document.getElementById().innerHTML lines. Neither my business info nor my map were displaying as they had before Jquery Mobile implementation. Once I removed the function initialize(){} from my code, as well as commented out my Google Maps implementation section in it's entirety, my business info displayed correctly.

CSS is driving my map and I don't think that is the source of my problem. My experience with this is limited at best, so hopefully someone may be able to point out an obvious error or structure to my code. It may be a DOM issue, but I can't identify it myself. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance for the help/comments.

```
// Read our the JSON data from source .php file

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://nsccpros.com/Directory_Test_App/get_Businesses_Json.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

var urlParameter = idStorageObject.b_id; 

// Var to hold google map coordinates

var mapLat;
var mapLon;

function myFunction(arr) {           // Checks if URL parameter matches a business ID from database (b_id)
    var out = "";                // Main output markup
    var panel_output = "";      // Panel markup
    var i;
    var mapTest = "";

    var panel_setup = "<div data-role=\"main\" class=\"ui-content\"><h3>View Business Info</h3><a href=\"#myPanel\" class=\"ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow\">Click Me!</a></div>";     // Additional Business Info Panel


    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i].b_id == urlParameter) {

            // ****** Business info output details ********

            out += "<div align='center'><div id='business_name'>" + arr[i].name + "</div></div>";   // Extra div tag which centers the business name

            out += "<table class='business_details'>";    // Create the table to hold business details

            out += "<tr><td class='photo' colspan = '3'><img class='business_image' src='images/" + arr[i].image + "'></td>";

            // Hours table (table within a table)
            out += "<td><table id='hours_table'><tr><th colspan='3'>Hours</th></tr>";
            out += "<tr><td class='day'>Mon</td><td class='hours_s'>" + arr[i].mon_start + "  - </td><td class='hours_c'>" + arr[i].mon_close +"</td></tr>";
            out += "<tr><td class='day'>Tue</td><td class='hours_s'>" + arr[i].tue_start + "  - </td><td class='hours_c'>" + arr[i].tue_close +"</td></tr>";
            out += "<tr><td class='day'>Wed</td><td class='hours_s'>" + arr[i].wed_start + "  - </td><td class='hours_c'>" + arr[i].wed_close +"</td></tr>";
            out += "<tr><td class='day'>Thu</td><td class='hours_s'>" + arr[i].thu_start + "  - </td><td class='hours_c'>" + arr[i].thu_close +"</td></tr>";
            out += "<tr><td class='day'>Fri</td><td class='hours_s'>" + arr[i].fri_start + "  - </td><td class='hours_c'>" + arr[i].fri_close +"</td></tr>";
            out += "<tr><td class='day'>Sat</td><td class='hours_s'>" + arr[i].sat_start + "  - </td><td class='hours_c'>" + arr[i].sat_close +"</td></tr>";
            out += "<tr><td class='day'>Sun</td><td class='hours_s'>" + arr[i].sun_start + "  - </td><td class='hours_c'>" + arr[i].sun_close +"</td></tr>";
            out += "</table></td></tr>";

            // Social media links
            out += "<tr><td><a href='" + arr[i].fb_link + "'><img class='social_icon' src='icons/fb.png'></a></td>";    // FB link
            out += "<td><a href='" + arr[i].twitter_link + "'><img class='social_icon' src='icons/twitter.png'></a></td>";   // Twitter link
            out += "<td><a href='" + arr[i].social3_link + "'><img class='social_icon' src='icons/pinterest.png'></a></td>";  // Social 3 link

            // Address info
            out += "<tr><td colspan = '3' class='address'>" + arr[i].street + "<br>" + arr[i].postal_code + "<br>" + arr[i].phone + "<br></td>";

            // Panel button
            out += "<td align='right' colspan = '2'>" + panel_setup + "</td></tr>";
            panel_output += "<p>" + arr[i].servicesP1 + "</p><p>" + arr[i].servicesP2 + "</p><p>" + arr[i].servicesP3 + "</p>";

            out += "</table>";

            // ---------------------------- End business info output details --------------------------------

            // ****Google maps implementation******

            // Assign latitude and longitude values

            mapLat = arr[i].mapLat;
            mapLon = arr[i].mapLon;

            // Configure google map options

            var pinLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(Number(mapLat),Number(mapLon));

            var mapProp = {
              center: pinLocation,  // Must cast the lat and lon values to number
              zoom:15,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);  // Draw the map

            // Draw the map pin on the map


            var startPosition = new google.maps.Marker({    // Create a new marker
            position: pinLocation,                        // Set its position
            map: map,                                // Specify the map
            icon: "images/pin.png"                            // Path to image from HTML
          }); 

    // ----------------- End Google Maps Implementation -------------------------------------------------

    // Output all business and map data

}}

    document.getElementById("businessDetails").innerHTML = out;
    document.getElementById("panel_output").innerHTML = panel_output;

}

function loadScript() // Adds a script tag to html header to load google map API on load
{
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: jQuerry should not affect the google maps... did you get error message? or were you able to track down the problematic code section by console.log()?

Comment: I checked through the logs using built in Chrome developer tools.. No warnings or errors.